# Cabal test coverage report is empty

Tags: haskell, cabal

Here is my project structure:

```
.git
src/
  exe/
    Main.hs
  lib/
    ModuleA/
    ModuleB/
    UnitTests/
      UnitTests.hs
    MainLib.hs
giter.cabal
```

I have an executable, and the only thing it does is call the `main` function form the library. Here is the contents of `src/exe/Main.hs`:

```hs
import qualified MainLib

main :: IO ()
main = MainLib.main
```

Here are the relevant parts of the giter.cabal file:

```
library 
    import: shared-properties
    exposed-modules: MainLib
    other-modules:
        ModuleA
        ModuleB

    build-depends:
      , brick
      , directory
      , fsnotify

    hs-source-dirs:   src/lib

executable giter
    import: shared-properties
    main-is:          Main.hs
    other-modules:

    build-depends:
        , giter
        , base
        , brick
    hs-source-dirs:   src/exe

test-suite giter-test
    type:             exitcode-stdio-1.0
    hs-source-dirs:   src/lib
    main-is:          UnitTests/UnitTests.hs
    default-language: Haskell2010
    other-modules:
        ModuleA
        ModuleB
    build-depends:
        , base
        , directory
        , HUnit
        , QuickCheck
```

Here is the result of `cabal new-test all --enable-coverage`:

```
.
.
.
[2 of 2] Linking /home/refaelsh/repos/giter/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-9.4.6/giter-0.1.0/build/giter/giter [Library changed]
Running 1 test suites...
Test suite giter-test: RUNNING...
Tests
  Events.hs
    handleSpecialKey_CommitOpen:   OK
    handleSpecialKey_CommitClosed: OK
    booleanDecision_True:          OK
    booleanDecision_False:         OK
  MainList.hs
    mainList_getUnstagedSlices:    OK
      +++ OK, passed 100 tests.
    mainList_getStagedSlices:      OK
      +++ OK, passed 100 tests.
    mainList_getTreeSlices:        OK (0.78s)
      +++ OK, passed 100 tests.

All 7 tests passed (0.81s)
Test suite giter-test: PASS
Test suite logged to:
/home/refaelsh/repos/giter/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-9.4.6/giter-0.1.0/test/giter-0.1.0-giter-test.log
Writing: hpc_index.html
Writing: hpc_index_fun.html
Writing: hpc_index_alt.html
Writing: hpc_index_exp.html
Test coverage report written to
/home/refaelsh/repos/giter/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-9.4.6/giter-0.1.0/hpc/vanilla/html/giter-test/hpc_index.html
1 of 1 test suites (1 of 1 test cases) passed.
Writing: hpc_index.html
Writing: hpc_index_fun.html
Writing: hpc_index_alt.html
Writing: hpc_index_exp.html
Package coverage report written to
/home/refaelsh/repos/giter/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-9.4.6/giter-0.1.0/hpc/vanilla/html/giter-0.1.0/hpc_index.html
```

Questions:

1. Both HTML files are empty, here is one of them (they both look the same):

```
module  Top Level Definitions   Alternatives    Expressions
%   covered / total %   covered / total %   covered / total
  Program Coverage Total    -   0/0     -   0/0     -   0/0
```

Why they are empty?

2. Why there are 2 HTMLs files? I was expecting one, only for the library part of the project.

Comment: I wonder if part of this issue stems from the fact that you have ModuleA and ModuleB as other-modules in the library and the test-suite. Thus, in your tests, if you import ModuleA or ModuleB, they are imported from the test-suite, not from your library. Perhaps, that affects the code coverage report. The only module that you are exporting is MainLib. Could you try exporting ModuleA and ModuleB from the library and not including them in the other-modules of the test-suite?

Comment: Could you please specify which HTML file's contents are shown in your question. Also, I would like to note that the cabal's logs claim to have written to more than two HTML files. Could you look at the contents of the hpc_index_fun.html files, the hpc_index_alt.html files, and the hpc_index_exp.html files. Perhaps those will reveal some insight :)

Comment: Also, I wanted to take a peek at more of the source code. Does this link point to your repository and the branch you are on? https://gitlab.com/refaelsh/giter/-/tree/feature-library/src/lib?ref_type=heads

Comment: @PeterBergman Thank you very much. I will try all of your suggestions from the first 2 comments.

Comment: @PeterBergman Regarding your 3rd comment: yes, that is the correct link.

Comment: I have been tinkering around with your repo, and I have noticed that there is a lot of confusion caused by the test modules having the same hs-source-dirs as the lib modules. A lot of the modules imported are not being imported from the library, but the hs-source-dirs, and consequently, those modules' code is not being picked up by Haskell Program Coverage.

Comment: I will try that also! Thank you :-)

Comment: I have a solution. I am typing up an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Both HTML files are empty, here is one of them

...

> Why they are empty?

**The shorter answer:**

Modules in the test suite's `other-modules` list are excluded from the reports.

**The simple solution:**

In your repository, just remove all of the `other-modules` from your test suite. Here is what that looks like:

```
test-suite giter-test
    type:             exitcode-stdio-1.0
    hs-source-dirs:   src/lib
    main-is:          UnitTests/UnitTests.hs
    default-language: Haskell2010

    build-depends:
        , base
        , directory
        , HUnit
        , QuickCheck
        , split
        , tasty
        , tasty-hunit
        , tasty-quickcheck
```

**The longer answer:**

In your unit tests, when you import ModuleA or ModuleB in the Main module defined in `src/lib/UnitTests/UnitTests.hs`, those modules are imported in a way that causes them to NOT be tracked by Haskell Program Coverage (the tool that is enabled by the `--enable-coverage` flag).

When you run `cabal new-test --enable-coverage`, ModuleA is not compiled with support for Haskell Program Coverage. This is because ModuleA is one of the `other-modules`. In order to compile ModuleA with support for Haskell Program Coverage, you must remove ModuleA from the `other-modules` list of your test suite.

That allows you to compile ModuleA with support for Haskell Program Coverage.

Now, you should see some content for ModuleA in the generated reports. You can do the same for ModuleB.

I hope this helps :)

---

> Why there are 2 HTMLs files? I was expecting one, only for the library
> part of the project.

The `.../giter-test/hpc_index.html` file is a report of the test coverage of the `test-suite giter-test`. It reports how much of the code is tested by the `test-suite giter-test`.

On the other hand, the `.../giter-0.1.0/hpc_index.html` file is a report of the test coverage of ALL the test suites. If you add another test suite that covers different parts of your code, then you will see a 3rd report for that new test suite, and the `.../giter-0.1.0/hpc_index.html` file would contain an aggregation of the reports for all of the test suites.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not understand the long version of the answer. But I did understand the snippet at the end and used it, and it solves the problem.

Comment: @RefaelSheinker I have changed the longer version of the answer and the code snippet. It is much simpler now. I see you have already pushed a commit to your repository. I wish I would have written what I did earlier.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering the second question. I also now understand the "long version".